# CTRL+D suddenly stopped working in Mac OS X Terminal, will not perform EOL operation

Tags: c++, macos, shell, terminal, eof

I have basic code that I am trying to run in terminal for a class. I am having trouble ending the code with the ctrl+d command once I am done typing. The code looks for the amount of certain characters, "e", vowel as well as counts total characters used. For hours yesterday I was able to use the Ctrl+D command to end my program and continue to edit/add to it but it stopped working suddenly.

I have noticed that when a string of "d"'s are inputted into the window, the return key is hit, and then ctrl+d is used, the programming successfully displays the data but otherwise any other input does not seem to give the EOF command that I am looking for.

I have tried resetting my terminal, saved the condition in which the "d" string worked and tried again. What is going on? After reading extensively on the topic I think it may be due to something else running in the background?

```
int main() {
    char ch;
    int ecount=0, vowels=0, other=0;
    cin.get(ch);
    while(!cin.eof()) {
        switch(ch) {
            case 'e':
                ecount++;
            case 'a';
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u': 
                vowels++;
                break;
            default:
                other++; 
        }
        cin.get(ch);
    }
    cout << ecount << " "<< vowels << " " << other << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you don't press return first, you have to hit Ctrl+D twice.

Comment: @thatotherguy I noticed that too - is that standard behaviour? Do you know what causes it?

Comment: Yes, this is expected. Ctrl-D just makes any pending read call to the terminal return with any currently buffered data, similar to Return (except then you also get a `\n`). If you press Ctrl-D after Return or Ctrl-D, the read call will return with 0 bytes, which by convention means end-of-input.

Answer (score 1):

You should not loop testing only `eof`.  There are other ways for the stream to error.  Just loop like this:

```
while( cin.get(ch) )
{
    // ...
}
```